# how to boot into safe mode in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I've been sifting through google search results and can't find the answer.

It seems F8 is not an option anymore.. however everything else shows how to boot into safe mode - *when you're already in windows.. argh...* that makes no sense, why do I need safe mode if windows is already working properly?

What I need is a way to boot straight into safe mode in window 10.. how can I do this? My screen is not working and i need to uninstall the graphics drivers - the regular "Type blindly your password" solution to this "Black Screen of Nothingness except a mouse cursor after windows 10 upgrade" problem is not working for me.. so I need to boot into safe mode and uninstall the nvidia drivers.

I don't have a windows CD since I upgraded from the internet. So I can't boot from that either.

So what's the official (or any) way to boot straight into safe mode ? thanks

Comment: For my asus latop, F8 is working, it brings you to a screen http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/07/21/e72c7a56-e0e7-4ff7-a6cb-5cd8e91601d1.png and choose http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/07/21/a1ffc991-843d-4fd6-b0f4-8853f754adfc.png http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/07/21/d161125d-d634-4448-becb-1fdc6d7ad824.png http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/07/21/645885f1-816c-4e9c-86b7-f6c12206a945.png http://kmpic.asus.com/images/2015/07/21/c462c661-37e2-4710-9bc9-87eaa2fcdb54.png

Comment: Besides, if you are urgent to boot into safe mode ASAP for troubleshooting purpose right now, try to power off the PC while windows is starting up. After two times, it also brings you to the above recovery environment.

Comment: do you have access to another computer with a DVD burner?

Comment: ah @bilo nice tip

Comment: @Keltari, yes but I have already a burned windows 10 dvd - it just wouldn't boot off that drive even before I upgraded - not really sure that the dvd drive still works - it's the slot loading type - this is an old asus atom HTPC

Comment: well, got into the option to start safe mode - unfortunately, even though it is supposed to be safe mode - it still has a black screen with mouse cursor... crap, I have to find a way to downgrade to 8 - I don't want to lose my files.. 8 was actually working for me quite nicely.. idiot to think I could upgrade so many computers without any problems (this was the third - first 2 worked fine - but upgrade path was 8.1 > 10 for those.. this was 8 > 10) .. the generally accepted rule of thumb has always been, never upgrade windows.. do a clean install - I'm a real idiot